Create a class that inherits properties from Mock. C#
I want to create a class that inherits properties from Mock. This way, when I call it, I can utilize the Setup methods and other functionalities seamlessly
This is my class
public class MockSettingsManager : Mock //  I know this doesn't work, but I want a similar solution to it
{
        private static SettingManagerCore singletonSettingManagerCore = null;
        private SettingManagerCore SettingManagerCore
        {
            get
            { 
             if (settingManagerCore== null)
             {
                 Mock<SettingManagerCore> settingManagerCoreMock = new Mock<SettingManagerCore>()
                 {
                   CallBase = true
                 };

                 settingManagerCore = settingManagerMock.Object;
              }

            return singletonSettingManagerCore;
            }
        }

      public virtual T GetSetting<T>(string name)
      {
         return SettingManagerCore.GetSetting<T>(name);
      }
}

Now  I want to call it like so
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    private MockSettingsManager settingsManagerMock = null!;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        settingsManagerMock = new MockSettingsManager() { CallBase = true };
        // This one should go to the callbase
        var test = settingsManagerMock.Object.GetSetting<string>("Test");

        // This one should retrive Test1
        settingsManagerMock.Setup(x => x.GetSetting<string>("Test")).Returns("Test1")
        test = settingsManagerMock.Object.GetSetting<string>("Test");
    }
}


Does anyone have any ideas, or is it even possible?

Could you please tell us what exactly do you want to achieve? I mean inheriting from Mock is the how. Could you please tell us the what part as well?

Instead of inheriting from Mock, you can define a function that encapsulates object creation, a Creation Method:
internal Mock<SettingManagerCore> CreateSettingManagerTestDouble()
{
    return new Mock<SettingManagerCore>() { CallBase = true };
}

This one is on the threshold of even being worthwhile to write, since there's little going on there, but it does give you a single point where you can define additional behaviour.
Then use if from your test:
settingsManagerMock = CreateSettingManagerTestDouble();
// This one should go to the callbase
var test = settingsManagerMock.Object.GetSetting<string>("Test");

// This one should retrive Test1
settingsManagerMock.Setup(x => x.GetSetting<string>("Test")).Returns("Test1")
test = settingsManagerMock.Object.GetSetting<string>("Test");

